# 2's complement representation of fractions?

Tags: math, binary, representation

I'm a little lost on this. I need to use two fractional bits 
`0.(a-1)(a-2)`

Like that, now I can use `.00 .01 .10` and `.11`
But I need negative numbers (in 2's complement) also, so would `.10` be `-.5` ? or would it be `-.25` ? 
The same with `.11` , that would be `-.75`? or would it be `-.5` ? 
I'm pretty sure it would be the former in both cases, but I'm not entirely positive.

Comment: P.S.  +1 for the "positive" pun.  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In two's complement notation, all of the most significant bits of a negative number are set to 1.  Let's assume you're storing these numbers as 8 bits, with 2 to the right of the "binary point."

By definition, `x + -x = 0`, so we can write:

```
0.5  +  -0.5 = 0.10 + 111111.10 = 0   // -0.5  = 111111.10
0.25 + -0.25 = 0.01 + 111111.11 = 0   // -0.25 = 111111.11
0.75 + -0.75 = 0.11 + 111111.01 = 0   // -0.75 = 111111.01
```

and so on.

Using 8 bits like this, the largest number you can store is

```
011111.11 = 31.75
```

the least-positive number is

```
000000.01 = 0.25
```

the least-negative number is

```
111111.11 = -0.25
```

and the smallest (that is, the most negative) is

```
100000.00 = -32
```

Comment: Thanks, this was closest, but I acctually figured it out...

`00=>0=>0/4=>0
01=>1=>1/4=>.25
10=>-2=>-2/4=>-.5
11=>-1=>-1/4=>-.25`

Answer (score 1):

see it this way:

you have normal binary representation

let's assume 8 bit words ...

the first bit (MSB) has the value 128, the second 64, and so on ...

in other words the first bit (MSB) is 2^7 ... the second bit is 2^6 ... and the last bit is 2^0

now we can assume our 8 bit word has 2 decimal places ....

we now start with the first bit (MSB) 2^5 and end with the last bit beeing 2^-2

no magic here ...

now to turn that into binary complement: simply negate the value of the first bit

so instead of 2^5 it would be -2^5

so base 10 -0.75 would be in binary complement
111111.01 ...
(1*(-32) + 1*16 + 1*8 + 1*4 + 1*2 +1*1 + 0*0.5 + 1*0.25)
(1*(-2^5) + 1*2^4 + 1*2^3 + 1*2^2 + 1*2^1 +1*2^0 + 0*2^(-1) + 1*2^(-2))

Answer (score 0):

A number stored in two's complement inverts the sign of the uppermost bit's magnitude (so that for e.g. a 16-bit number, the upper bit is -32768 rather than +32768).  All other bits behave as normal.  Consequently, when performing math on multi-word numbers, the upper word of each number should be regarded as two's-complement (since its uppermost bit will be the uppermost bit of the overall number), but all other words in each number should be regarded as unsigned quantities.

For example, a 16-bit two's complement number has place values (-32768, 16384, 8192, 4096, 2048, 1024, 512, 256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, and 1).  Split into two 8-bit parts, those parts will have place values (-32768, 16384, 8192, 4096, 2048, 1024, 512, and 256); and (128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, and 1).  The first set of values is in a two's complement 8-bit number, times 256; the latter set is an unsigned 8-bit number.

Comment: If your number was unsigned, your bits would have values (+1/2) and (+1/4).  For two's-complement format, flip the sign of the top bit, so they're (-1/2) and (+1/4).  The available values are then 0, 1/4, -1/2, and -1/4.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have 2's complement values composed of 1 bit for sign, 5 bits for the integer part and 2 for the fractional part.
You remember you can calculate the opposite of a value in 2 ways: 1) invert all bits and add 1 to LSB; 2) copy all the rightmost 0s (if any), copy the first 1 you encounter (from right to left), invert all the remaining bits.
We have:

```
 0.25 -> 000000.01
-0.25 -> 111111.11

 0.5  -> 000000.10
-0.5  -> 111111.10

 0.75 -> 000000.11
-0.75 -> 111111.01
```

You can also read this thread: [Two's Complement of fractional numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70350373/twos-complement-of-fractional-numbers/77874273#77874273)