# Two's Complement of fractional numbers

Tags: binary, computer-science, twos-complement

I've been searching around the web for a solution for this question for several weeks but without any success.

My University professor told me that to convert a binary number with a fractional part to a negative number in Two's complement we must do this:

1)Convert the number from base 10 to base 2
(+4.25) = (0100.0100)

2)**The only part we need to convert in two's complement right now is the part before the point.**

0100 -> 1011 -> 1011 + 1 -> 1100

So for him, -4.25 in two's complement is (1100.0100) without any conversion for the fractional part.

For me, this solution is wrong because if we try to add up these two numbers we get

0100.0100 +
1100.0100 =
0000.1000

that's 0.5 not 0

Comment: I have no idea what your professor meant.  Perhaps he was somehow referring to the fact that -4.25 means -(4 + 1/4) rather than -4 + 1/4.  [I made this mistake once in some code.] But still. . . .

Answer (score 2):

For a fraction you do exactly the same as a normal integer, meaning invert all the bits and +1 to the Least significant bit for your representation:
4.25  = 0100.0100 
-4.25 = 1011.1100 
Also can't come up with anything your professor could have meant.

Answer (score 1):

Your professor is simply wrong.

This statement refers to a negative value with a fractional part:
"The two’s complement representation is formed by inverting the bits of the absolute value and adding a 1 to the least significant (rightmost) bit."

- Sarah L. Harris, David Harris, in Digital Design and Computer Architecture, 2022
  Chapter 5.3.1 Fixed-Point Number Systems
  The LSB is located on the fractional part. So even the fractional part changes, unless it just a sequence of 0s.

Moreover, Fixed-Point is usually stored in microprocessors as integers, where you as a programmer must know where the point is and where it moves (e.g. in multiplications). The CPU does not know it is a fixed point value and treats it as an integer.